# Issues with my htaccess - rewriting user

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In the most simplest terms, I am trying to redirect user from faq.html to Help/Frequently-Asked-Questions. Now the below code partially works. In the sense that the url does show the clean url, but the faq.html page itself cannot be found for the clean url acts as a page of its own when it is just rewriting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Activate rewrite engine

RewriteEngine On

# Establish the base
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /faq.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Help/Frequently-Asked-Questions [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^faq.html$ help/Frequently-Asked-Questions [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd rule is doing reverse. Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /faq\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ Help/Frequently-Asked-Questions [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^help/Frequently-Asked-Questions/?$ faq.html [L,NC]
```